# Use of grammar "be + to be + past participle"

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

My question is regarding the structure "**be + to be + past participle**". An example of that is:

- The water is to be poured.

How can I interpret that grammatical structure?

- The water is to be poured = The water is going to be poured

or

- The water is to be poured = The water will be poured.

Thank you in advance for the explanation provided.

Answer (score 1):

This is the "**[be + to-infinitive](http://www.grammaring.com/be-to-infinitive)**" construction which is used to express:

1. **official arrangements** *(will)*

   - *The Prime Minister is to visit India next month.*
2. **official orders** *(should)*

   - *At the end of the course, all students are to take a written exam.*
3. **things that should be done** *(must/should/need to)*

   - *What am I to do?*
4. **a possible aim when saying what should be done to reach it** *(ought to/must/need to)*

   - *If you are to work here for more than three months, you must have a residence permit.*
5. **prohibition** *(only in the negative)*

   - *You are not to do that again.*
6. "**Be + to-infinitive**" can also be used in the past

   - *Mr Jones was to speak at the meeting. (it was arranged and he did)*
7. But "**was/were + to + perfect infinitive**" means that the arranged event did not actually happen

   - *Mr Jones was to have spoken at the meeting, but he had to cancel because of his illness.*

---

To answer your question, "**The water is to be poured**" can be an "**official arrangement**", an "**official order**", or "**things that should be done**".

However, we often use "**Be to + passive infinitive**" when giving instructions. So your sentence is basically just an instructive one and means "**The water should be poured**".

> **Footnote**: *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, p.206, calls the BE to VERB construction **quasi-modal be**.

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola Not my fault 'ere since it's not I who's writing it, but the system that quotes the user I comment to.

Comment: Okay, sorry, now, if we were writing correct English grammar for a paper, it would be "it's not **I** who **am** writing it"; right, Alex?

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola: yes, if you choose to use the conlang invented by prescriptive grammarians. Myself, I prefer to use English.